# django model with only one CharField is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I have a very basic 'Place' model:

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and I'm trying to review it using the app: https://github.com/diefenbach/django-reviews

When trying to add a review to certain Place object, in the app's views https://github.com/diefenbach/django-reviews/blob/master/reviews/views.py, it reaches te 'save' method and actually saves a record in the database. However it raises the following TypeError:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://ec2-54-77-118-44.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/reviews/add/11/1

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'south',
 'places',
 'reviews')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  199.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py" in process_response
  38.                     request.session.save()
File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in save
  57.             session_data=self.encode(self._get_session(no_load=must_create)),
File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in encode
  87.         serialized = self.serializer().dumps(session_dict)
File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/signing.py" in dumps
  88.         return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py" in dumps
  250.         sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in encode
  207.         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in iterencode
  270.         return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in default
  184.         raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Exception Type: TypeError at /reviews/add/11/1
Exception Value: <Place: Teteria India> is not JSON serializable
```

I don't understand why this error raises if I'm still not using any AJAX or JSON and as far as I could see neither does the reviews app's views. Does it have anything to do with the forms?

And anyway, how can it be that a model with only one CharField is not JSON serializable? Do I have to provide the serialization?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the line 148, it store `object` in the session

```
request.session["last-rated-object"] = object
```

then perfoms a redirect to reviews_thank_you's view

```
def thank_you(request, template_name="reviews/thank_you.html"):
    """Displays a thank you page.
    """
    if request.session.has_key("last-rated-object"):
        object = request.session.get("last-rated-object")
        del request.session["last-rated-object"]
    else:
        object = None

    return render_to_response(template_name, RequestContext(request, {
        "object" : object,
    }))
```

It is returning the `object` without serialize it and i think here is the problem. Can you edit that view to return a serialize version of you `object`?

Comment: I use the view from https://github.com/diefenbach/django-reviews/blob/master/reviews/views.py

In fact, it only stores the 'new_review' object as you can see in the line 140 of the file, and in fact, it does save it successfully.
The problem should be in line 148 when assigning the 'Place' object to the request.session. But I still do not know how to solve it... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MartíBosch can you please, pasted the full trace of the error ?